# c Implementation of Inheritance

Tags: c, inheritance, macros

I'm trying to figure out a good way to do semi-inheritance in c.

This is what I've come up with

```
//statemachine.h
...
#define CHANGE_STATE(newState)                   \
    do {                                         \
        printf("[%s]->", stateStrings[state]);   \
        state = newState;                        \
        printf("[%s]\r\n", stateStrings[state]); \
    } while (0)
```

.

```
//trafficlight.c
#include "trafficlight.h"
#include "statemachine.h"

// Is a state machine
typedef enum {
    green,
    yellow,
    red
} traffic_state;

static const char * stateStrings [] = {
    "green",
    "yellow",
    "red"
};

static traffic_state state = red;

// Move to the next signal
void lightChange(void) {
    CHANGE_STATE((state+1)%3);
}
```

The idea being any module that wants to be a state machine (i.e. makes use of CHANGE_STATE) must define state and stateStrings.

Just looking for feedback on this approach.

EDIT:

Question moved to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63272/c-implementation-of-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

A common way to use inheritance is to use casts, `struct` inside `struct`-s, and mimic [vtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable) (i.e. pointers to constant `struct`-s containing function pointers).

Look for example inside [GObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject) inside Glib from GTK. Read the [Gobject documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) and study the many macros implementing GObject.